# Google pagespeed Insights lists JS and CSS pushed through http2 as render blocking

Tags: apache2, pagespeed, http2

I am pushing some of the critical CSS and JS files using Http2 push, yet the google Pagespeed insights mark those files as render blocking.

Is there any way to address this issue or the Google Pagespeed Insights is still using old engine, which doesn't recognize the pushed assets properly.

Note:
I have checked the same in Chrome console, the files are pushed properly without any issue.